# Modulus and float numbers

Tags: python, modulus

How modulus are interpreted is by saying *how many times "a" can reach to "b"* but not by multiplying, just by adding up.

If we were going to find the modulus of `20` from `1.3`, it will add up `1.3 + 1.3 +...+ 1.3 = 19.5` which `20-19.5` will be `0.5`.

But if we operate the formula that everyone explains with modulus, that's by dividing and multiplying and then getting the remainder, we will not get an exact number, for example:

`6%2 = 0` and `7%2 = 1` because `6/2 = 3` times and `3*2 = 6`, that's why answer is 0 and 1, but if we use `20 % 1.3` this will be `20/1.3 = 15.384615` and `15.384` times multiplied by `1.3` is `15.384615385 * 1.3 = 20` therefore this formula is not true, and shows the inability of expressing how modulus operates with float numbers, but by adding up `1.3` and then not passing `20`, it will give `1.3` added `15` times = `19.5`. `20 - 19.5 = 0.5` therefore we have an exact remainder.

I wanted to know if this approach is correct, and how does Python interprets modulus?

Comment: Check out the CPython source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4e0ce820586e93cfcefb16c2a3df8eaefc54cbca/Lib/_pydecimal.py. Search for `divmod`

Answer (score 1):

> 20 % 1.3 this will be 20/1.3 = 15,384615 and 15,384
> times multiplied by 1,3 is 15,384615385 * 1,3 = 20 therefore this formula
> is not true…
>
> I wanted to know if this approach is correct

Your computation is incomplete; therefore the conclusion is wrong.

You have to take the integer part, i. e. 15, multiply by 1.3, which gives 19.5, and subtract that from 20. This yields 0.5 as expected.

For Python's implementation see [`float_rem()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L607). It uses [`fmod()`](http://manpages.org/fmod) to compute. The output representation is generated by [`float_repr()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L345), which calls [`PyOS_double_to_string()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/pystrtod.c#L796).
We get the same output with the C expression `printf("%.17g\n", fmod(20, 1.3))`.

It shouldn't be a surprise that floating point computation results are sometimes inexact.

Comment: Yeah I know that method, but still it floats and gives 0.49999933 number, which is not "exactly", therefore if you want to modulus a float number you will need to do it manually, and code a formula, I want to know how does python operates the modulus, since it's not 0.5 but 0.499999933

Comment: I expanded the answer.